# Oracle right justify column heading along with also right justifying the data

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is it possible for Oracle to right justify column heading along with also right justifying the data?

Comment: this is tool dependent. you don't say which one you're using.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Which tool or language do you use to display your data?

Answer (score 3):

DBMS doesn't care about the formatting of your data (given that you are not using left-padded CHAR(N) datatype). It depends on the client which uses the data.